# Why anime.js doesn't work on a click in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, animation, anime.js

Now, thanks to mounted (), the animation works successfully when the page is updated, but for some reason the animation does not play when you click on it.

console.log is output on a click, but there is no animation. What was my mistake?

```
<template>
  <div class="compHeader">
    <h1 class="testVal" style="position: absolute;">QWERTY</h1>
    <button type="button" class="testClick" @click="testClickGo().restart">+</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    methods: {
      testClickGo(){
        console.log(111);
        return this.$anime({
          targets: '.testVal',
          translateX: 200,
          delay: 800
        });
      }
    },
    mounted(){
      this.testClickGo();
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you try replacing this `@click="testClickGo().restart"` to this `@click="testClickGo"`?

Comment: yes, but to no avail =(

Comment: and `testClickGo()`?

Comment: it doesn't work either

Comment: Do you really need this inline style on the `<h1>`? You can remove it or add the click event to the h1 tag.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question.

```
<template>
  <div class="compHeader">
    <h1 ref="animeEl">hello, world!!</h1>
    <button @click="anime.restart()">click me</button>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
data: () => ({
  anime: null,
}),
mounted() {
  this.anime = this.$anime({
    targets: this.$refs.animeEl,
    translateX: 200,
    delay: 800,
  });
}
</script>
```